# Agrupamento de dataframe com ordenação

Tags: python-3.x

Estou com uma dificuldade e não sei mais como avançar.
Tenho um DataFrame onde estou fazendo um agrupamento por algumas colunas e no aggregate dele eu pego uma dessas colunas e uso o size para fazer um count, porém gostaria de exibir essa lista com ordenação decrescente. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

```
boarded_vl.groupby(['day_of_week', 'boarded_at']).aggregate({'boarded_at' : np.size})
```